# Cannot import onnxruntime in python Windows

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to run **onnxruntime** model on **[CPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kdQF.png)** laptop… but I get an error when trying to import onnxruntime…

Has anyone tried to use this module?

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\onnxrunti
me\capi\_pybind_state.py:13: UserWarning: Cannot load onnxruntime.capi. Error: '
DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.'
  warnings.warn("Cannot load onnxruntime.capi. Error: '{0}'".format(str(e)))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import onnxruntime
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\o
nnxruntime\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from onnxruntime.capi._pybind_state import get_all_providers, get_available_
providers, get_device, RunOptions, SessionOptions, set_default_logger_severity,
NodeArg, ModelMetadata, GraphOptimizationLevel, ExecutionMode
ImportError: cannot import name 'get_all_providers' from 'onnxruntime.capi._pybi
nd_state' (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-package
s\onnxruntime\capi\_pybind_state.py)
```

Answer (score 0):

see the failure - "DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found"
. I don't know how it is in windows, but in linux you need to add the lib path to the environment variable "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=path_to_lib"... (in windows I think you need to set the PATH: C:> set PATH=%PATH%;full_path_here;...).
First check that you have the lib. In the onnx folder (you should be in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-package
s\onnxruntime) check which lib python is trying to load: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-package
s\onnxruntime\capi_pybind_state.py their is a line :

```
try:
    from onnxruntime.capi.onnxruntime_pybind11_state import *
```

Check that you have onnxruntime_pybind11_state lib somewhere in the onnxruntime folder.
Iif you have it - than adding the onnxruntime folder to the env lib path should do it....